# Intersection & wellordering question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question I'm tackling doesn't seem to make much sense:

"let $X \neq\emptyset$, $X \subseteq \omega$. Show that there is $n \in X$ with $n \cap X = \emptyset$".

I tried to think about a proof by contradiction but got nowhere, so turned to proof by induction and thinking about the Wellordering Theorem.

Thanks to a comment, I know understand the statement itself, but am not any closer to proving it. Any hints, even on the kind of proof?

Comment: In order for $1\cap X$ to be non-empty, you'd have to find an *element* of $1$ that is also an element of $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n = \min(X)$. Then if $m \in n$, this means $m < n$ and so $m \notin X$, by minimality, so $n \cap X= \emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you! Very simple and elegant

Comment: @Atlas You already suggested well ordering was the key.. I just had to show you were right.. Glad to help.